# SDWebImage linking issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sdwebimage, image-caching

I am trying to use SDWebImage framework for asynchronous loading and caching images.
I could integrate SDWebImage project in to my project and build successfully. But I cannot use this line of code

```
[pCell.imgViewThumb sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aPromo.picture_url_thumb] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
```

It gives this error

```
No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'
```

But the **sd_setImageWithURL:** method and the class already added in the project. I tried several times cleaning the project, re-linking the frameworks etc...
But didn't work

[image]

[image]

Comment: May I ask you did you download the last version of the file?

Comment: use `pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7.1'` to install it.

Comment: should I use "pod init" before use pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7.1'?

Comment: Here is a complete tutorial:http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2

Comment: Previously I tried with a previous version of SDWebImage pod file. Using this use pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7.1' I was able to fix the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: @sajaz Please add add an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the latest 'SDWebImage' pod file using this
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7.1'
Issue fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the category. Type

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

on top of the file.

Comment: Where have you imported the category? It needs to be in the same file you are calling the `sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` method

Comment: Yes. I have done it correctly. I'll update the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to import the SDWebImage category file? I believe it is called UIImageView+WebCache.h. The code would look like (at the top of your file with the other imports):

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"